# Remove class with a fadeout after a Timeinterval is completed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout, fadeout

I've been able to remove a class with a `setTimeout(function()`, but now it just removes instantly, so I was wondering on how I can make it `fadout();` aswell.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.pagina-laden').removeClass('pagina-laden');
},2000);
```

.pagina-laden is the class where there is a background-image in css. But now I just need to fadeout out instead of abruptly vanishing.
Thanks for the effort and help!

Comment: [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Comment: Or add an animation in the CSS and it will do it automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `.delay()` method

Heres a demo

```js
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
  $("#fadeMeOut").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
#fadeMeOut {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickMe">click me and wait</button>    
<div id="fadeMeOut"></div>
```

Comment: Psst... how'd you get the hat?

Comment: Put `.fadeOut(500)` before the delay.

Comment: sorry i assumed your removal of the class was having the effect of fading out, I have updated to use the jquery fadeout

Comment: Not sure on the hat, it just appeared

Answer (score 0):

You can try below setTimeout function for that.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.yourClass').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}, 3000);
```